# QlikView error while creating QVD file

Tags: qlikview

I have a view in my database (Oracle) and I use this view to export data to a QVD file. I use QlikView for exporting to this QVD via a QVW file, and I want to automatically run it 2 times every day.

So I put it onto a server and I scheduled it to run 2 times every day. When I run the QVW script manually, it exports the correct QVD file. However, when it is scheduled, I have an error like this in the log file:

```
QVX_UNEXPECTED_END_OF_DATA: 
Error: OLEDB read failed
General Script Error
Execution Failed
Execution finished.
```

I tried to run for each column (in my view) one by one. My problem is in the `WHERE` clause:

```
select ...
from ...
where ...
and ACTUAL_DATE  >= to_date(sysdate, 'dd.MM.YYYY hh24:mi:ss')
```

I removed this `"ACTUAL_DATE  >= to_date(sysdate, 'dd.MM.YYYY hh24:mi:ss')"` and it runs perfectly, but when I add this clause back, I get an error.

What could I do to solve this?

Comment: Could this be a timeout because it takes a lot of time to  get the newest data?

Comment: I don't think so. Because when i run manually, it was taking almost 5 minutes.And qvd file include 90.000 rows.

Comment: Btw. you don't need to cast sysdate.

Comment: i cast sysdate because ACTUAL_DATE's format is 'dd.mm.yyyy'. Also i tried "ACTUAL_DATE >= sysdate" and i didn't work.

Comment: What datatype is ACTUAL_DATE? Most query tools just show date portion of an Oracle timestamp (DATE datatype). If datatype of ACTUAL_DATE is DATE you will need no cast. If it's VARCHAR2 (or similar) you would need to cast TO_CHAR( .. ) !

Comment: ACTUAL_DATE's datatype is date. When i removed this condition, it was fine. When i put this condition, i could reload manually but i could not scheduled.

Comment: This is the right condition then:
and ACTUAL_DATE  >= sysdate

Comment: As suggested by @ralfbecher remove the cast and everything will be fine. This is a common issue with oracle.